# Reduce power conssumption while wireless should be used

Tags: java, android

I am working on my MSc dissertation right now. This dissertation has one related app which should be developed by android. One of the objectives of the research is about using wireless to sync data among the phones. In the meanwhile, I must consider power consumption which means reduce power consumption while using wireless. I am thinking about 3 possible wireless technologies for this app:

- wifi direct (p2p wifi) - fast, reliable, but not supported on many phones (even ones with Android >=4.0) (you would also probably need to two devices to test/develop this)
- regular wifi - fast, reliable, but requires at least an access point (i.e. some infrastructure, or another mobile device acting in part as an access point but does NOT Need internet access), code partially compatible with wifi direct
- Bluetooth - slow, unreliable, supported on most devices, requires no infrastructure (also probably need two devices to develop), code least

Regarding these mentioned wireless technologies, I have few questions listed below (please consider that I need acceptable evidences or documentations to support my ideas):

1. Which of these technologies consume less power?
2. How can I reduce power consumption in android phone?
3. Are there any practical strategies available in this case regardless of coding? For example consider sth in setting of the app or sth else?

Answer (score 1):

> I am working on my MSc dissertation right now.

My advice would be not to get bogged down with the power optimization issue.  Your **primary** goal should be to get your thesis done ... and do any necessary coding that *directly* required to achieve that.  From reading your question, I get the impression that power usage minimization is at best a peripheral issue (no pun intended).  Assuming my impression is correct, you should not wasting your limited time on this.

Now if your primary goal was to produce product quality software, my advice would be different ...

Comment: Hmmm, I never thought of it this way, but the quote about premature optimization can fit not only for optimizing performance, but for optimizing power consuption too... (I'd give another +1 for the 'peripheral issue' expression if I could)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend investigating [Bluetooth Low Energy, or Bluetooth Smart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_low_energy) as it is called too. Also, there is [ANT+](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANT+). These both are very conservative regarding power usage.